# Tietze Extension Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I saw [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem). Since its [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tietze_Extension_Theorem) is non-trivial, I tried whether we can clarify it intuitively for functions of one real variable. So, in this special case, I am trying to prove that if $f\colon K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, with $K$ closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function of $\mathbb{R}$.

To prove this, I proceeded as follows: $K^c$ is open, hence it is disjoint union of open intervals. We try to extend $f$ continuously on each connected component, say $(a,b)$ of $K^c$. Since $a,b$ are elements of $K$, we define $f$ on $(a,b)$ in such a way that its graph on $(a,b)$ is the line with end points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b)$. In this way, $f$ can be defined on complement of $K$, and it seems to me obvious that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Am I correct with this proof in one variable case?

Comment: I think this works, yes. The interesting case is taking $K$ like the Cantor set.

Comment: You might also be interested in my old paper ‘A "More Topological" Proof of the Tietze-Urysohn Theorem’, *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. 85, No. 3 (Mar., 1978), pp. 192-193, in which I prove it using a more sophisticated version of the usual proof of Urysohn’s lemma.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Thanks for useful suggestion. I will see it.

Answer (score 4):

For metric spaces you can do another approach as well (yours is very specific for the reals), following Engelking exercise 4.1F, but the result is due to Hausdorff.

Let $(X,d)$ be metric and suppose $A$ is closed in $X$, and $f: A \rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous. Then define

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x \in A \\ \inf{\left\{f(a) + \frac{d(x,a)}{d(x,A)} - 1\,:\,a \in A\right\}} & \text{if } x \in X \smallsetminus A\end{cases}$$

and show that $F$ is continuous.

(For unbounded functions use the $\arctan(f)$ to make it bounded first.)

Comment: What is the motivation for defining this function?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad the quotient of distances tends to $1$.